# Query to remove character and text from field

Tags: sql, postgresql, replace

I am working with a PostgreSQL database. I have a column that contains rows that look like this:

[image]

I am to replace the 'PC' text with '00000' and then remove the period and all text after.
So for example, row 5 should look like 0000055000 after the transformation.

I was able to the 'PC' with the overlay function. So my current query looks like this:

```
select set_name, overlay(set_name placing '00000' from 1 for 2 )  FROM
src.sap_setnode 
WHERE set_name LIKE'PC%'
```

From there how can I remove the period and everything after it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SPLIT_PART(REPLACE(set_name ,SUBSTR(set_name ,1,2),'00000'),'.',1) FROM t WHERE set_name LIKE 'PC%' OR set_name NOT LIKE 'PC-%' OR set_name NOT LIKE 'PCA%'
```

Comment: Thanks - this is the answer I found as well. I think this way works best.

Comment: This doesn't looks like a valid query

Comment: 'cos you're missing closing brackets and `FROM` clause at least.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found the answer - if anyone has a similar question. The split_part function can be used to split the field by using '.' as a delimiter and then grabbing the first part.

SELECT
split_part( overlay(set_name placing '00000' from 1 for 2 ),'.',1)  FROM
src.sap_setnode

Answer (score 0):

Try to use regular expression, for example:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET set_name = regexp_replace(set_name, '^PC(.+)\..+$', '00000\1');
```

I'm not entirely sure that this covers all the corner cases you might encounter, so you might need to tweak the regex a bit :)

Also documentation for `regex_replace`:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html

Answer (score 0):

using regexp_replace:

```
select  regexp_replace (regexp_replace(set_name,'^PC','00000') , '\.(.*)', '');
```